# MS Graph API: Assign keyCredentials and requireResourceAccess to application

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I wanted to create an app on AzureAD so I created it manually via https://portal.azure.com and it worked well. Also, my friend created a powershell (not core) script to do the same thing and it worked.

However, I wanted to make an app via MS Graph API which is much easier to use on multiple platforms and found a document like the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta

It worked well on Graph explorer:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

But, I still don't know how to add keyCredentials (cert) and requiredResourceAccesses.

Based on [application resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-beta), it seems there is a way to create to update those values but no idea at all.

Could anybody give a hint for solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this MS graph api : [Update application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta), you can find what you want in the [request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta#request-body).

**Important**: APIs under the `/beta` version in Microsoft Graph are in *`preview`* and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

[image]

[image]

**Sample**:

Request URL:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{App Object ID}
```

Request body:

```
{
   "keyCredentials": [],
   "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
           "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
           "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "863451e7-0667-486c-a5d6-d135439485f0",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
       ]
    }
   ]
}
```

It works on my side.

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you. One thing I struggle with is "keyCredentials": [ {"keyId": "someValue", part. As far as I know, keyId of KeyCredentials is object id of the current app as UUID. When I tried it, graph API returned `When present, application key identifier cannot be empty and can be at most 32 bytes.\r\nParameter name: applicationKeyIdentifierValue"` issue.

Comment: @sangheestyle The `keyId` is a GUID, but I dont think it is the object id of the ad app.

Comment: Yes, that is `GUID`. Sorry about that. :) Here is why I thought like that is based on AAD Powershell doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential?view=azureadps-2.0 It says `Specifies a unique ID of an application in Azure Active Directory.` But, on MS Graph REST API beta doc, `keyId` is `The unique identifier (GUID) for the key.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/keycredential?view=graph-rest-beta#properties It shows nothing special for it.

Comment: When, I manually register credential on azure portal after creating app via Graph API, keyId is not the same with appId or object id of the app. So, still wondering...

Comment: @sangheestyle The `Specifies a unique ID of an application in Azure Active Directory` i.e. `ObjectId ` you mentioned is the property of the powershell  `New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential`, it means which the ad app you want to create KeyCredential for, not means the `keyId`, you could refer to the Example 1 in the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential?view=azureadps-2.0#examples

Comment: Yes, you are right. With my powershell script using `New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential` , it worked well. But, I still don't know what value should be used for keyId for PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/:appObjectId. I used 1) a random GUID 2) app id 3) app object id ... none of them is working. I think I am missing something now.

Comment: I think I was overthinking. `keyId` in this context seems key id of cert.

Comment: Solved: `keyId` is not required for request body. It is generated from the server side. `customKeyIdentifier` can be generated from `openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha1 -inform pem -in server.crt` and `key` can be generated from `base64 server.crt`